# Gson - Same field name, different types Serialize

Tags: android, api, gson, retrofit2

Sorry for my bad english. I have the same problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28319473/gson-same-field-name-different-types) but i need Serializate. For send post to restfull api service in Android with Retrofit
Somebody help me? Thanks

My question is, how implement custom serialize whit gson? because i need Serialize this json. whit gson.

The Json is:

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "IdEncuesta": 1,
    "Resultado": 
    [
        {
            "NumeroPregunta": 1,
            "TipoPregunta":1,
            "Respuesta": "Pepito"
        },
        {
            "NumeroPregunta": 2,
            "TipoPregunta":2,
            "Respuesta": 2
        },
        {
            "NumeroPregunta": 3,
            "TipoPregunta":3,
            "ListaRespuestas":[
                {
                    "numeroOpcion":1,
                    "Respuesta": 3
                },
                {
                    "numeroOpcion":2,
                    "Respuesta": 5
                },
                {
                    "numeroOpcion":3,
                    "Respuesta": 2
                },
                {
                    "numeroOpcion":4,
                    "Respuesta": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "NumeroPregunta": 4,
            "TipoPregunta":4,
            "ListaRespuestas":[1,3,5]
        }
    ]
}
```

The pojo is:

```
public class RespuestaEncuesta{
    @SerializedName("userId")
    @Expose
    public String userId;
    @SerializedName("IdEncuesta")
    @Expose
    public Integer IdEncuesta;
    @SerializedName("Resultado")
    @Expose
    public List<RespuestaEncuesta.Resultado> Resultado = new ArrayList<RespuestaEncuesta.Resultado>();

    public class Resultado {
        @SerializedName("NumeroPregunta")
        @Expose
        public Integer NumeroPregunta;
        @SerializedName("TipoPregunta")
        @Expose
        public Integer TipoPregunta;
        @SerializedName("Respuesta")
        @Expose
        public String Respuesta;
        @SerializedName("ListaRespuestas")
        @Expose
        public List<Integer> ListaRespuestas = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste your json please...

Comment: Post your POJO/ bean class.

Comment: read the docs here: it helps https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html

Comment: what are the possible value types you will be getting under `ListaRespuestas`?.. right now you have `JsonObject` and `Integer`

Answer (score 1):

```
{  
   "userId":1,
   "IdEncuesta":1,
   "Resultado":[  
      {  
         "NumeroPregunta":1,
         "TipoPregunta":1,
         "Respuesta":"Pepito"
      },
      {  
         "NumeroPregunta":2,
         "TipoPregunta":2,
         "Respuesta":2
      },
      {  
         "NumeroPregunta":3,
         "TipoPregunta":3,
         "ListaRespuestas":[   //ListaRespuestas has a relational object, ok
            {  
               "numeroOpcion":1,
               "Respuesta":3
            },
            {  
               "numeroOpcion":2,
               "Respuesta":5
            },
            {  
               "numeroOpcion":3,
               "Respuesta":2
            },
            {  
               "numeroOpcion":4,
               "Respuesta":1
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "NumeroPregunta":4,
         "TipoPregunta":4,
         "ListaRespuestas":[ //ListaRespuestas don't have a relational object, where is it ?
            1,
            3,
            5
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

THIS CAUSE A JSON SYNTAX EXCEPTION, I do not know if that is your question, but the error I found was this.

Comment: My question is, how implement custom serialize whit gson? because i need Serialize this json. whit gson.

Answer (score 0):

I guess better solution is there than mine.. 
What I am doing here is for `ListaRespuestas` I will check first item is `JsonObject` or `Integer/Premitive` and according to that I am reading the data.

```
    try {
        RespuestaEncuesta t = gson.fromJson(json, RespuestaEncuesta.class);
        for (RespuestaEncuesta.Resultado item : t.Resultado) {
            if (item.ListaRespuestas != null) {
                JsonElement element = item.ListaRespuestas.get(0);
                if (element.isJsonObject()) {//check element/item is JsonObject or Integer
                    for (int i = 0; i < item.ListaRespuestas.size(); i++) {
                        JsonObject object = (JsonObject) item.ListaRespuestas.get(i);
                        //System.out.print(" J Object  " + object.get("numeroOpcion").getAsString());

                    }
                } else {
                    //System.out.println("Json Primitive");
                    for (int i = 0; i < item.ListaRespuestas.size(); i++) {
                        JsonPrimitive object = (JsonPrimitive) item.ListaRespuestas.get(i);
                        //System.out.print(" J Integer " + object.getAsInt());
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException | JsonIOException | FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```