# JSON parsing with GSON with same name in objects & arrays

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson

I have json response ,where I have the array & objects with same name. I could not parse it with GSON. Is it impossible to parse that kind of json response with Gson? or, there is some way to parse the response with GSON?

**Example of response:**

```
 {
      "content": [
                   {
                     "type": "text",
                      "content": "adnan",
                      "class": "32",
                      "align": "1"
                   },
                   {
                     "type": "image",
                     "image": "http://adnanul.jpg",
                     "width": 590,
                     "content": "sarkar",
                     "height": 332,
                     "link": "http://hashtagfail.com/post/44606137082/mobile-services-android-serialization-gson",
                     "caption": "3",
                     "class": "332"
                   }
               ]
            }
```

Comment: how could you do it?

Comment: Add the exception, but there shouldn't be any problems using this JSON with GSON.

Comment: Drup Desai already posted a nice answer, but it would be interesting to see your parsing code.

Comment: Exception is: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 26643 path $.data[1].content[27].content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error -

```
Exception is: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 26643 path $.data[1].content[27].content
```

The problem is that, content field inside content field is a array not a String, that is not shown inside your code example, but it is what the exception means. It could be that in some cases content is a String and in some cases an array.

Here is a similar problem and a answer -
[Gson - Same field name, different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28319473/gson-same-field-name-different-types)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to archive this response.

```
    public class ContentEntity {

        private ArrayList<Content> content;

        public class Content {
            private String type;
            private String image;
            private int width;
            private int height;
            private String content;
            private String link;
            private String caption;
            @SerializedName("class")
            private String className;

// Add getter and setter here
        }
    }
```

try using below entity while parsing it using GSON.

Comment: what exception are you getting.

Comment: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 26643 path $.data[1].content[27].content

Comment: I think your json is not starting as Json object it must be starting with Json array

Answer (score 0):

Using default representation will propably cause this because you have keys with same name. Maybe writing an own deserializer will help.

Lets asume that you have a Java class name "Content" and the json-String represents an array of this object:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Content.class, new MyBrandNewContentDeserializer());

Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
Content[] conts = gson.fromJson(jsonInput, Content.class);
```

Within the deserializer you can react on the String type "content"

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ . Just provide your json , select JSON as source type and then select Gson as annotation style. It will generate a POJO class